# ANSYS CFX Memory Boundary Tag Issue

Tags: ansys

I am trying to learn ANSYS CFX at the moment and the other day all of a sudden I could not import any saved project mesh from ANSYS Meshing into CFX-Pre. Even files that would open perfectly fine before hand now all of a sudden dont open and I get the following error.

ERROR
There was a problem importing the mesh from the requested file.
The importing process reported the following problem:

Unable to import mesh: Can't open <(PathToProject)> for reading.
Reason: cgio_open_file:ADF 16: Internal error: Memory boundary tag bad.

I replaced the actual path with (PathToProject)

I have also tried using verifiable working mesh in different file types other than the .wbpj file type that the meshing tool from ANSYS saves in. I have also tried reinstalling ANSYS, moving projects to a different drive and even limiting RAM usage just in case it was a weird edge case with memory allocation but no luck.

I'm probably making a very dumb and simple mistake, so I apologize in advanced, again, I just started learning recently.